# File Transfer over LAN from Seagate Personal Cloud Drive to Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server

I currently have files on a 5TB Seagate Personal cloud drive which is hardwired into my router. I also have a Ubuntu Server 16.04 machine wired into the same router. I am using `rysnc` to copy files from the Seagate to the Machine. I am doing this on the physical machine, not through SSH. I am only getting transfer speeds of about 16MB/s, I have about 3.8TB to move, it's going to take days at this rate.

Any thoughts of speeding it up?

ifconfig output

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:4d:7b:89:50:ab
      inet addr:192.168.1.14  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::724d:7bff:fe89:50ab/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:52740642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5953720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:78559542476 (78.5 GB)  TX bytes:476995043 (476.9 MB)
      Memory:fe700000-fe71ffff
```

I used the following command to make the sync:

```
sudo rsync -avzP from_location to_location
```

Comment: Do both devices have gigabit Ethernet NICs? If not, there's your problem right there.

Comment: the seagate personal cloud says it does in the settings, how do I check the local machine?

Comment: just checked motherboard it is a gigabit

Comment: You can do `sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Speed`

Comment: Also, which type of Ethernet cables are you using to connect the two machines? Cat5e? And how long is the cable run?

Comment: standard cables that come with device nothing fancy and cords are less than 10 feet in length. Just did grep speed got 1000 / s